# Firebase iOS set priority not updating query

Tags: ios, firebase

I am experiencing a problem with correctly observing a Firebase query with the iOS library. The problem only occurs when updating the priority on the same client. Below is a test case to demonstrate the issue I am running into.

I would like to observe the child count for a particular priority. The `countLabel` simply displays the number of children with priority "one". There is a button that triggers `changePriority()` to make the new child's priority "two". I would expect the `countLabel` to display 0 (or decrement to the correct number), but it does not update.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let firebaseRoot = Firebase(url: "url goes here")
    var newChild: Firebase?

    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firebaseRoot.queryEqualToPriority("one").observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            self.countLabel.text = snapshot.childrenCount.description
        })

        newChild = firebaseRoot.childByAutoId()
        newChild?.setValue(true, andPriority: "one")
    }

    @IBAction func changePriority() {
        newChild?.setPriority("two", withCompletionBlock: { (error: NSError?, firebase: Firebase!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                NSLog("Priority updated to `two`")
            } else {
                NSLog("Error updating priority: %@", error!)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Importantly, if I change the priority of that child using another client (or Vulcan), the query observer responds correctly, and the `countLabel` will show the correct number.

Comment: You haven't declared any error handlers here or callbacks to see if the operations succeed. It seems likely the client op fails to update priority.

Comment: @Kato, I have been using [Vulcan](https://github.com/firebase/vulcan) to verify that the client code is properly updating the server. Also, based on the [Firebase event guarantees](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-guarantees), it seems that the listener should fire even if the server has not yet been updated. I think this may be a bug with the iOS client, and have submitted it to Firebase support as well.

Comment: @Kato I have updated the sample code to use the completion block when updating priority. The completion block is called without an error, and I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry it took us a while to get this answered. Been a busy week here. If you need any assistance beyond Michael's answer, please contact support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in the Firebase iOS SDK.  Thanks for bringing it to our attention!  Fortunately, we're actually revamping our queries support and currently have a beta SDK available which, in addition to having new functionality, fixes this bug.  If you want to give it a shot, check out http://www.firebase.com/docs/beta/queries

Else, if you wait a couple weeks, these features (and the bug fix) will make it into the release SDKs.